# Program Transformation to Disintermediate Isomorphic Representation Transforms

Tags: program-optimization, abstract-data-types

Given two representations of the same abstract data type, any optimal program that incorporates one representation has a corresponding optimal program that incorporates the other.

What is the field of computer science that studies program transformation between two such optimal programs?

If necessary, posit the practically restrictive, but analytically convenient, case that the representations are isomorphic rather than homomorphic.

Comment: What do you mean by an "optimal program"?  Optimal in what sense?  What does it mean for a program to "incorporate a representation"?  What do you mean by isomorphic in this context?   Can you define your terms?  Can you give an example?  I encourage you to edit the question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: "Optimization" is a well understood term:  The process of discovering the program that maximizes the objective function or finds a point on the Pareto frontier of a multi-objective function.